# The power series $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{x^{n}}{n(2n-1)}$ with $2$nd Taylor polynomial and Taylor series. [Solved]

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I have been a fool not noticing it earlier. Instead of deleting this thread I have chosen to put the short solutions of this problem. This thread is closed.

> Consider the series $$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{x^{n}}{ n(2n-1)}\tag{1}$$ and the
>   sum is denoted by $f(x)$.
>
> Determine the second Taylor polynomial for $f(x)$ about $x=0$.
>
> Determine the Taylor series of $g(x)=2xf''(x)+f'(x)$ about $x=0$.

Answer to i). Since $(1)$ is itself a Taylor series to the sum function $f(x)$ around $x=0$ so the answer is $P_{2}(x)=x+x^{2}/6$ for all $x\in (-1,1)$.

Answer to ii). See the answer of Claude Leibovici.

Comment: The function $f(x)$ is written in its Taylor expansion then the second order polynomial is drop all the terms with order greater than two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{ n(2n-1)}$$  $$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{ (2n-1)}$$ $$f''(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n-1)x^{n-2}}{ (2n-1)}$$ So $$g(x)=2x f''(x)+f'(x)=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n-1)x^{n-1}}{ (2n-1)}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{ (2n-1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

**Edit**

The long (and **stupid**) way would have been to identify what is $f(x)$. Using partial fraction decomposition $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{ n(2n-1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Big(\frac{2}{2 n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\Big)x^n=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{2 n-1}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}$$ The second summation is just $\log(1-x)$. The first one is more tricky but, looking at the Wikipedia page about Taylor series, there is one which is really appealing $$\tanh^{-1}(y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{y^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$ So, after some simple manipulation $$f(x)=\log (1-x)+2 \sqrt{x} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do we have to identify a function $g(x)$ before we start with the Taylor expansion? I like that one.Though I am too sceptic with the summations where they were combined into one or vice versa. For example, the series (1) at my post is convergent for $x\in [-1,1]$, but the series $-\sum_{n\geq 1}x^{n}/n$ is not convergent if $x=1$ or the function $x\mapsto \log(1-x)$ is not continous at $x=1$. Is there another way to answer the first case i) without identifying the expression of $f(x)$?

Comment: You are very welcome ! As I wrote, identifying $f(x)$ would be the **most stupid** way to do it.  In your case $f(x)$ is already a Taylor series, so we just use it as given for building the Taylor series of $g(x)$.